# Google Pagespeed жалуется на несуществующие шрифты

Tags: google-page-speed

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот это показывает Google PageSpeed. Сначала он жаловался на обычные шрифты, которые лежат у меня в папке на сервере, я прописал им нужный display и больше google на них не жалуется. Но остались эти. Я сделал поиск по содержимому всех файлов на хостинге, нигде он не нашёл ничего связанного с woff2 (а как видите, он жалуется на шрифты с таким расширением).

Comment: Зачем Вы ищете эти файлы на хостинге, если они запрашиваются с https://fonts.gstatic.com? Ищите упоминания этого шрифта — Roboto.